# Catching javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, sslexception

I am using good old-fashioned `HttpURLConnection` to fetch a bitmap (this is handled asynchronously) along the following lines:

```
Bitmap bmp;
boolean fetchOk = false;
try {
    URL url = new URL(strURL);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(timeoutConnectMs);
    connection.setReadTimeout(timeoutReadMs);
    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode == 200) {
        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
        fetchOk = true;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // I also catch and handle specific Exceptions differently but there is also a catch-all here
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
if (!fetchOk) {
    // handle retry
    return;
}
// do stuff with fetched bmp
```

Just occasionally, the fetched bitmap isn't complete... it stops part-way down and is blank for the lower part.  Or sometimes it is blank completely.  This bitmap ends up in a widget, which is where I sometimes see these incomplete / blank bitmaps.

I *think* it when the phone wakes up after a sleep, and I've had users reporting similar.  When it has happened to me, the following was in the log:

```
D/My_Stuff(11449): isBitmapInCache: true
D/My_Stuff(11449): getViewId for widget_port
D/My_Stuff(11449): nothingToDo: false
W/System.err(11449): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x73401b5d88: I/O error during system call, Software caused connection abort
W/System.err(11449):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
W/System.err(11449):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.read(NativeSsl.java:411)
W/System.err(11449):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket$SSLInputStream.read(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:583)
W/System.err(11449):    at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:145)
W/System.err(11449):    at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:213)
W/System.err(11449):    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:61)
W/System.err(11449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1xStream.java:602)
W/System.err(11449):    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:61)
W/System.err(11449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine$2.read(HttpEngine.java:1007)
W/System.err(11449):    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:397)
W/System.err(11449):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
W/System.err(11449):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:875)
W/System.err(11449):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:850)
W/System.err(11449):    at com.myapp.thisis.MyGetStuffTask.call(MyGetStuffTask.java:277)
W/System.err(11449):    at com.myapp.thisis.MyGetStuffTask.call(MyGetStuffTask.java:31)
W/System.err(11449):    at com.myapp.thisis.TaskRunner.lambda$executeAsync$1$TaskRunner(TaskRunner.java:61)
W/System.err(11449):    at com.myapp.thisis.-$$Lambda$TaskRunner$-iWF_J4qwWx8b2L_xWSWxOSc0Nk.run(Unknown Source:6)
W/System.err(11449):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err(11449):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err(11449):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
D/skia    (11449): ---- read threw an exception
D/My_Stuff(11449): showMessageInWidget (Finishing up…)
D/My_Stuff(11449): getTextViewId for message_port
```

There is normal logging before and after the `SSLException`, and the process completes normally after the exception, just with an incomplete bitmap being the result.  In other words, the `SSLException` doesn't seem to be caught by the `catch` block, so there doesn't appear to be any way to catch this and deal with it.

I think it may be related to [this issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/5475) (I understand that `HttpURLConnection` uses `okhttp` under the hood for Android 4.4+ and hence why `okhttp` appears in my log despite not using the `okhttp` library directly).  There, they also associate the problem with doze mode.  But there is no resolution of this problem over there either.